# Does the covariant derivative commute with the variational derivative?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

Say we have a (compactly supported normal) variation of a surface $\Sigma$ immersed in $\mathbb{R}^3$,  $\mathbf{r}: \Sigma \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\frac{\partial{\mathbf{r}}}{\partial t} = u \mathbf{N}$ where $\mathbf{N}$ is the unit normal vector field of the surface and $u: \Sigma \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is some smooth function.

Let $f_{ij}$ denote the twice-covariant derivative of a smooth function $f: \Sigma \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, with respect to $i$ followed by $j$.  In computing stuff like $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\,(f_{ij})$, does it make sense to write $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\,(f_{ij}) =^? (f_t)_{ij}$$ where $f_t$ is the $t$-partial derivative of $f$?

My hunch is that it's more complicated than this, but I don't have  a good reason for my skepticism.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be clear: $f_{ij}(x,t_0)$ should be the second covariant derivative of $x \mapsto f(x,t_0)$ with respect to the metric induced on $\Sigma$ by the immersion $x \mapsto \mathbf{r}(x,t_0)$?

Comment: Yes, maybe I should have specified.  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the metric on $\Sigma$ is changing in time, it is indeed more complicated than this. I think it's easiest here to do a coordinate calculation; so we'll start with the formula $$f_{;ij} = \partial_i \partial_j f - \Gamma_{ij}^k \partial_k f$$for the second covariant derivative. Differentiating this in time and commuting partial derivatives we find 
\begin{align}
\partial_t f_{ij} &= \partial_i \partial_j \partial_tf-\Gamma^k_{ij}\partial_k\partial_tf-(\partial_t\Gamma^k_{ij})\partial_kf\\
&=(\partial_tf)_{ij} - (\partial_t \Gamma^k_{ij})\partial_kf; \tag{1}
\end{align}
so your proposed formula needs a correction term due to the variation of the induced connection. To get a formula for the variation of $\Gamma$, we will first  need to know the variation of the induced metric, which we can find with the product rule: we have
\begin{align}
\def\r{\mathbf{r}}\def\v{\mathbf{v}}\def\N{\mathbf{N}}
\partial_t g_{ij} &= \partial_t\left(\partial_i \r \cdot \partial_j \r\right)
\\ &=\partial_i \v\cdot\partial_j\r+\partial_i\r\cdot\partial_j\v
\end{align}
where $\v = \partial_t \r = u \N$ is the velocity. Expanding this using the facts $\N\cdot \partial_j r= 0 $ and $\partial_i \N \cdot \partial_j r = A_{ij}$ (here $A$ is the second fundamental form) we find

$$h_{ij} := \partial_t g_{ij} = 2u A_{ij}.$$

Plugging this in to the formula $$\partial_t \Gamma^k_{ij} = \frac 12 g^{kl}\left(-\nabla_l h_{ij} + \nabla_i h_{jl} + \nabla_j h_{li} \right) \tag{2}$$ for the variation of the connection yields
$$\partial_t \Gamma^k_{ij} = g^{kl}\left( -A_{ij}u_l +A_{jl}u_i + A_{li} u_j-u\nabla_l A_{ij} + u\nabla_i A_{jl} + u\nabla_j A_{li}\right).$$ (You can prove (2) easily using geodesic normal coordinates - if you get stuck, it's Prop 3.6 [here](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~andrews/book.pdf).)

Sticking this back into (1) gives you the formula you want. You can simplify it a little using the fact that $\nabla A$ is totally symmetric (from the Codazzi equation), which lets you cancel the fourth and fifth term.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely sure about the context of your question and whether you mean by $f_ij$ the $ij$ coordinate of $\nabla \operatorname{d}f$ or whether you firstly apply $\nabla_i$ on $f$ followed by application of $\nabla_j$ (here $\nabla$ refers to the covariant derivative). This answer is focused on the second case *which is not tensorial* (unlike the first case!). Hopefuly my answer won't be missleading and will provide some help.

$\Sigma$ is some embedded surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and thus has dimension $2$ so we need (and have, at least locally) $2$ coordinate functions that describes $\Sigma$. Since the domain of $f$ is $\Sigma \times \mathbb{R}$, we are working with $3$ coordinates and hence it makes sense to consider derivatives in different coordinate directions $i,j$ and $t$. Important point: *the covariant derivative of a function is simply the directinal derivative* (classical partial derivative). That is, according to the interpretation of your notation discussed above, $f_{ij} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i \partial x^j} $. From the Schwartz theorem (see this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives)) we know that the partial derivatives of a function commute. Putting these two facts together we have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f_{ij} = f_{ijt} = f_{itj} = f_{tij} = (f_t)_{ij} \ .$$

Comment: The [second covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_covariant_derivative) of a function is the covariant derivative of a covector field, which cannot be written in terms of partial derivatives alone.

Comment: Indeed we have $\nabla f = \operatorname{d} f $ where $\operatorname{d} f$ is the differenitial of $f$ which is a covector field. On the other hand, $\nabla_i f$ (which OP denotes $f_i$) is evaluation of $\operatorname{d} f $ on vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ is a scalar field given by directional derivative of $f$. Thus applying $\nabla_j$ on $\nabla_i f$ should again be a directional derivative. I guess that should we use non-coordinate directions, the lie bracket arrising from double covariant differentiation would not vanish, yet this is not our case. Do I miss something?

Comment: In conventional usage the second covariant derivative $f_{ij}$ refers to $(\nabla d f)_{ij} = \partial_i \partial_j f - \Gamma^k_{ij} \partial_k f$, not $\nabla_{\partial_i}( \nabla_{\partial_j} f) = \partial_i \partial_j f.$ The former is tensorial in $i,j$ while the latter isn't. I guess it's up to the OP to clarify which they are talking about, but the former seems much more likely to me.

Comment: True true, I will edit my answer for it might cause more confusion then help in its actual version.

Comment: Radek, thank you very much for your answer, but Anthony is right.  I am referring to the tensorial quantity  ($\nabla{df})_{ij}$.  I appreciate the help anyway, however.